# Purpose of `key` in Aggregation Binding Info

Tags: sapui5

The API Reference of [`bindAggregation`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation) explains that the binding info property `key` is useful to improve update behavior in models.

> The name of the key property. [...] This can be used to improve update behaviour in models, where a key is not already available.

However, that explanation is somewhat incomplete which makes me wonder *in which cases* it's actually useful to provide a key property.

Sure, I can provide the key on every single aggregation binding definition but then I'm doing something without knowing "why" exactly. On the other hand, the above quote also tells me implicitly that *there are* cases where a key is already available. So I browsed through the source code and found that ODataListBinding (V2) has [`getEntryKey`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c7f55607e635caf5014502d8ea540aca818d2fd1/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataListBinding.js#L221) which provides each binding path as a `key` value. However, that method is called nowhere in my projects.

Has anyone experienced any significant improvements of "update behavior in models" due to the provided `key`?

---

I'm aware of [this case](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1736#issuecomment-338991820) where a key is helpful to allow combining two-way data binding with `growing` enabled controls (despite the doc saying that it's [not allowed to combine them together](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1736#issuecomment-341452596)). But I don't think that's the actual use case of `key`.

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation topic *[Extended Change Detection](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/7cdff73f308b4b10bdf7d83b7aba72e7)* (ECD) section "Using Extended Change Detection in App Development" answers most of the question:

> If a control [..] supports *extended change detection*, you should **make sure that each entity of your model has a unique key** to improve performance.
>
> - **For OData models, the unique keys are automatically provided.**
> - For all other models (like a JSON model), you have to define the keys either by using a key property [name] or by using a function that calculates the `key` in the binding info of their list binding [...].

Whenever the list/table data collection changes, ECD allows skipping destruction of the entire entries (e.g. `sap.m.ListItem`s) but to update only partially. For that, as described in the documentation, a valid `key` property in the aggregation binding is required for non-OData models.